# The OnClickListener for individual views in ArrayAdapter gets mixed up

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

Whenever I click the `ImageView` which has a `OnClickListener`, I get the `URL` of that object that is meant for the next `View` on the bottom of my screen, that has yet to get on the screen.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View rowView = convertView;

    if(rowView == null){
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

        //Creëer een Viewholder om alles statisch op te slaan in het geheugen
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.subreddit = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.subreddit);
        holder.source = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.source);
        holder.score = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.score);
        holder.image = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.image.setTag(position);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }


    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("com.tolgap.json.TEST");
            i.putExtra("page", holder.thing.url);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }

    });

    holder.thing = gegevens.get(position).data;
    holder.title.setText(holder.thing.title);
    holder.subreddit.setText(holder.thing.subreddit);
    holder.source.setText(holder.thing.domain);
    holder.score.setText(holder.thing.score);
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(plaatjes.get(position));        

    return rowView;
}
```

And here is the code for the `ViewHolder`:

```
static class ViewHolder{
    Result thing;
    TextView title;
    TextView subreddit;
    TextView source;
    TextView score;
    ImageView image;
}
```

I've read a few things about using the `setTag()` method, and I've tried this, but I didn't quite get what I had to put as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in storing the `Result` data object in the `ViewHolder`:

```
static class ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    TextView subreddit;
    TextView source;
    TextView score;
    ImageView image;
}
```

The `getView()` method:

```
//...
else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
}
Result obj = gegevens.get(position).data;
holder.image.setTag(obj.url); // It's a String I guess?!?
holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String toPass = (String) v.getTag();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.tolgap.json.TEST");
        i.putExtra("page", toPass);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

});
holder.title.setText(obj.title);
holder.subreddit.setText(obj.subreddit);
holder.source.setText(obj.domain);
holder.score.setText(obj.score);
holder.image.setImageBitmap(plaatjes.get(position)); 
return rowView;
}
```

Comment: But the URL I'm trying to pass to the intent is on the result object. Do I have to set the holder Tag to be the URL I'm passing to the ClickListener?

Comment: Oh sorry. Tried to read the code on my phone and misread the part where you had set the tag. Thank you. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you declaring the holder variable?  Make it a local final variable and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I also tried doing this afterwards, after reading about final variables. This worked, without using any tags. I only declared the Result object as a final variable and it worked.